# The use of English Article "the"

Tags: grammar, articles

Can someone tell and explain to me which sentence uses the definite article correctly?

1. Force is denoted by *the symbol F*.
2. Force is denoted by *symbol F*.

When we talk about proper nouns like the name of a person after the title, we don't use the definite article.

For example,

> He is President Trump.

We don't say "he is *the* President Trump." Is it true in the above case?

Comment: If you read the Tour properly you will see that this is not a site for English Language Learners — There is a separate SE site of that name.

Comment: Either could be correct, but they mean different things. Is there a list of symbols say A-Z?

Comment: To @Edwin-Ashworth: Although any letter from A-Z can be used to denote force, but generally, "F" is used.

Comment: In this context, the meanings can be extremely similar, but have slightly different connotations.

Comment: Seems like the sentence you're trying for is "Force is denoted by the symbol F." (Since your comment puts it in a Physics context, not a Star Wars context.)

Comment: @Ken-Mohnkern: Yes, it should be "force," not "the force."

Comment: Normally, in English, one would say, "Force is denoted by *F*.

Comment: 'Force is denoted by symbol F' is correct if there are various symbols presented, and the symbols are lettered. If they were numbered, 'Force is denoted by symbol 23' say might be correct. If 'F' is the actual symbol rather than the symbol's label, the definite article is required (though @aparente001's suggestion is also valid [not binding]).

Comment: I understand your question better now.  Yes, it follows the same pattern.